# How to keep latest 0 in raw digest hash while transfer it through pipe?

Tags: python, bash

Python 2.7.9

uname -a: `Linux kali 4.0.0-kali1-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.0.4-1+kali2 (2015-06-03) x86_64 GNU/Linux`

python code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import hashlib
import base64

def f( msg ):
        print 'f():'
        print 'msg: ' + msg
        m = hashlib.md5()
        m.update( msg )
        print 'm.hexdigest(): ' + str( m.hexdigest() )
        print 'm.digest(): ' + str( m.digest() )
        b64 = base64.b64encode( m.digest() )
        print 'b64: ' + str( b64)

msg="hello"
f(msg)
msg='{"HelloId": 2}'
f(msg)
msg='{"HelloHelloId": 2}'
f(msg)
```

bash code:

```
#!/bin/bash


f(){
echo 'f():'
msg="$@"
echo "msg: $msg"
md5="$(echo -n $msg | openssl dgst -md5 -binary)"
md5_hex="$(echo -n $msg | openssl dgst -md5 | awk '{print $2}')"
echo "m.hexdigest(): $md5_hex"
echo "m.digest(): $md5"
b64=$(echo -n "${md5}" | python -c 'import base64; import sys; print base64.b64encode( sys.stdin.read() ),')
echo "b64: $b64"
}

msg="hello"
f $msg
msg='{"HelloId": 2}'
f $msg
msg='{"HelloHelloId": 2}'
f $msg
```

Seems pure python is right and it is latest 0 in hash sum:

python output:

```
$ python base64_test.py
f():
msg: hello
m.hexdigest(): 5d41402abc4b2a76b9719d911017c592
m.digest(): ]A@*�K*v�q��Œ
b64: XUFAKrxLKna5cZ2REBfFkg==
f():
msg: {"HelloId": 2}
m.hexdigest(): 7a6c4e0b7be519c95941fc0018581ae0
m.digest(): zlN
               {��YA�X�
b64: emxOC3vlGclZQfwAGFga4A==
f():
msg: {"HelloHelloId": 2}
m.hexdigest(): 72dc42e42036d7068010b2598780ab2d
m.digest(): r�B� 6���Y���-
b64: ctxC5CA21waAELJZh4CrLQ==
```

bash output:

```
$ bash base64_test.sh
f():
msg: hello
m.hexdigest(): 5d41402abc4b2a76b9719d911017c592
m.digest(): ]A@*�K*v�q��Œ
b64: XUFAKrxLKna5cZ2REBfFkg==
f():
msg: {"HelloId": 2}
m.hexdigest(): 7a6c4e0b7be519c95941fc0018581ae0
m.digest(): zlN
               {��YA�X�
b64: emxOC3vlGclZQfwYWBrg
f():
msg: {"HelloHelloId": 2}
m.hexdigest(): 72dc42e42036d7068010b2598780ab2d
m.digest(): r�B� 6���Y���-
b64: ctxC5CA21waAELJZh4CrLQ==
```

Take a look,

1. `"hello"` - both are equal.
2. `'{"HelloId": 2}'` - wrong latest base64. However hexdigests of md5 hashes are equal.
3. `'{"HelloHelloId": 2}'` - are equal again.

It is not a space or upper letter or anything else like this...

Seems, it is latest 0 in second hash `...c0018581ae0`. How to keep this 0???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was in inability of bash to keep binary `null` character in variable.

Simply, bash can not working with binary.

Solution:

```
b64=$(echo -n $msg | openssl dgst -md5 -binary | python -c 'import base64; import sys; print base64.b64encode( sys.stdin.read() ),')
```

Means, need no to store binary in variable, and simply push it through pipes to the end - base64-output.